# How to make an object immutable

Tags: c#, .net

**Original**

I have an object as a result of Ef 6.0 . I have a single instance of it and want to make sure that ,no other code is able to change its values.

Is there any architecture ,pattern to make sure of it. Immutable,struct,readonly nothing is so clean. or am I asking for too much form such popular language?

**Edited**

I have an object as a result of Ef 6.0 .
I have a single instance of it and want to make sure that ,no other code is able to change its values.

1.Is there any architecture ,pattern to make sure of it.
**Immutable pattern ,struct,readonly** nothing is usable with EF.
Am I asking for too much form such popular language?

2.Is there a way to lock an object after required changes are done ?

Comment: Private property-setters?

Comment: readonly isnt clean?

Comment: Singleton design pattern?

Comment: @mickey: Singleton can be mutable.

Comment: "Nothing is usable with EF" points to the fact that if you don't want code modifying your EF entities, you shouldn't be passing them around - you can build domain objects backed by EF entities which are themselves immutable without issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't have any member that can change the content of your class, like property setters (make the setters `private`).

Don't let methods change your variables. (You should make them `readonly` probably).

Only mutate fields, properties and variables from the constructor.

Basic example:

```
public class X
{
    public X(string y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }

    private readonly string y;
    public string Y { get { return y; } }
}
```

Comment: @L33TS: if you initialize an object you don't mutate it per definition.

Comment: It should be noted that if your class contains instances of mutable objects, external code will still be able to modify *those* instances; e.g., if your class owns an instance of `List<T>`, even if you only expose a getter to your member, external code will still be able to modify this list. In this instance, you can use the `ReadOnlyList<T>` wrapper class to build a truly immutable class, but if you're exposing types which are mutable themselves, you may need to create your own read only wrappers.

Comment: @Thunder: That is a new requirement that wasn't there before. You asked how to make it immutable. If you don't want it to be that (by giving another meaning to immutable), you should make that clear.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have included original question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Think of all the value objects you use. date is a good one. You can take the class' data as part of the constructor and assign those only once at construction. As already pointed out you can make property fields private to set and public to get. For state changing functionality you can return a new instance from the state changing method. A good example is the AddDays method on DateTime. This leaves the original date unchanged but gives you back a new date with the appropriate days added to the original DateTime.

```
Var date = new DateTime(2015,01,01);
Var newDate = date.AddDays(15);
// date is now 2015,01,01
// newDate is now 2015,01,16
```

I found this to be the most effective pattern especially as you start needing state changing logic. Great in a multi threaded environment.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for making Ef objects immutable :

Private property-setters.

```
 public class Users
    {
        public int Id { get;private set; }
        public string FirstName { get;private set; }
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
    }
```

Courtse
–  J. Steen

Comment: That will work... How do you intend to change any of the properties? You don't have a constructor...

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thats the point to make the properties unchangeable. this will really needed eg when working with Meta data that must not be changed.

Comment: But they won't have a value to start with.

Comment: I tested Users poco class as given here with EF , Ef could set the users class with data somehow !

Comment: I guess they use reflection to get the private property setters and use it. Still, this isn't really immutable, but if it works for you, fine :) .

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question but I was having the same problem and come up with the following solution, leaving it here so that someone else may benefit in the future:

```
OriginalData = Context.Entry(MyBindingSource.Current).CurrentValues.ToObject();
```

Note that MyBindingSource.Current is my entity here.